# the isupper(), islower(), toupper(), tolower() functions not working in c++

Tags: c++

I have a code fragment something like this:

```
char choice;
do
{
    cout << "A. Option 1" << endl;
    cout << "B. Option 1" << endl;
    cout << "C. Option 1" << endl;
    cout << "D. Option 1" << endl;
    cout << "Option: ";
    cin >> choice;
    if(islower(choice) == 0){ toupper(choice); } // for converting Lower alphabets to Upper alphabets so as to provide flexibility to the user
}while((choice != 'A') && (choice != 'B') && (choice != 'C') && (choice != 'D'));
```

but it does not converts the Lower alphabets to Upper alphabets... I don't know why... The OS I am using is Windows 7 and the Compiler is Visual C++(please note that I have tested this code in other compilers to but the same problem)...

Comment: Try `choice = toupper(choice);`

Comment: Also, `islower(choice) == 0` means that it only converts when the char is not lowercase (already uppercase)...

Comment: hey guys the modified code is: `if(islower(choice) != 0){ choice = toupper(choice); }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the returned value, [`toupper`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/toupper) takes a character by value (not reference) and returns the upper case result:

```
choice = toupper(choice);
^^^^^^^^
```

Also, the condition should be inverted:

```
if (islower(choice)) // not: if(islower(choice) == 0)
```

Use this code, `toupper` itself checks if the character is lower case or not:

```
cin >> choice;
choice = toupper(choice);
```

Comment: Since `char` may be signed and passing a negative value (other than `EOF` if that happens to be negative) is undefined behavior the code should really be `toupper(static_cast<unsigned char>(choice))`.

Answer (score 2):

This line of code

```
if(islower(choice) == 0){ toupper(choice); }
```

should be re-write as below,

```
if(islower(choice)){ choice = toupper(choice); }
```

The function,

```
int toupper ( int c );
```

Return Value
The uppercase equivalent to c, if such value exists, or c (unchanged) otherwise. The value is returned as an int value that can be implicitly casted to char.

[toupper](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/toupper/)

Answer (score 1):

`islower` and `isupper` tells whether character is upper case or lower case or not.

`toupper` or `tolower` does not convert. It takes `int` parameter and returns an `int` which is converted character.

To convert use the following:

```
  choice = toupper(choice);
```