# Why are my char functions not doing their job?

Tags: c++

So I am still new to C++, and I'm trying to make a program that has the user input a string, and then my functions return the string in reverse case, all lower case, and then all uppercase. Instead I just keep receiving the first letter of the string back, always uppercase. Not sure what I am doing wrong. Any suggestions?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

char answer[255] = "";
int max = strlen(answer);

void reverse() {
    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
        if (islower(answer[i])) {
            isupper(answer[i]);
        }
        else if (isupper(answer[i])) {
            islower(answer[i]);
        }
        else if (isspace(answer[i])) {
            isspace(answer[i]);
        }
    }
    cout << answer[max];
}

void lower() {
    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
        if (isupper(answer[i])) {
            islower(answer[i]);
        }
        else {
            answer[i] = answer[i];
        }
    }
    cout << answer[max];
}

void upper() {
    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
        if (islower(answer[i])) {
            isupper(answer[i]);
        }
        else {
            answer[i] = answer[i];
        }
    }
    cout << answer[max];
}

int main() {

    cout << "Please enter a word, or a series of words: " << endl;
    cin >> answer[max];

    reverse();
    lower();
    upper();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Post your code as text, not as an image. It would just make it a whole lot easier for us to go through and debug it, and maybe come up with a solution.

Comment: Picture has been removed and I entered it in. Sorry, created an account just to post this.

Comment: no probs.. Buddy, isLower and isUpper can only CHECK if the character is upper or lower case. Doesn't convert it to that case.

Comment: To convert to upper, use `toUpper` and for lowercase, use `toLower`.

Comment: `cin >> answer[max];` will read exactly one character because `answer[max]` is exactly one character, the first character. In C++ you have to do things in order. For example, `int max = strlen(answer);` will provide an answer based on what is in that string at that time. Since the string was initialized one line earlier and contains an empty string, `max` will be 0.

Answer (score 0):

[`islower(char)`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/islower/) is just a built in function to **check** if the `char` is in lowercase or not. Same goes with [`isupper`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isupper/). It **does not change** the case of the character.

In order to convert to lowercase/uppercase, use [`tolower`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/tolower/)/[`toupper`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/toupper/). This would return the character in the converted case. But, it is important that you need to **assign the returned value to the character itself**.

Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20042834/10232790) for some more clarity related to `islower`, `isupper`, `tolower` and `toupper`.

- And now coming to the point why it's printing just the 1st character: As @user4581301 has mentioned in his comment,

> "*cin >> answer[max]; will read exactly one character because answer[max] is exactly one character, the first character. In C++ you have to do things in order. For example, int max = strlen(answer); will provide an answer based on what is in that string at that time. Since the string was initialized one line earlier and contains an empty string, max will be 0.*"

Hence your `cin` should be `cin >> answer`. **BUT**, this will accept the 1st word of your sentence. In order to accept all the words including the spaces, use `getline()` instead. And for using this, `answer` should be declared as `string answer` instead of a char array.

This is how you accept a full sentence: `getline(cin,answer);`

- And your variable `max` will give an error in a few compilers as being ambiguous. This is because of the `using namespace std;`. to avoid this, rename `max` to something else, like `maxlen`.
- And finding the length of `answer`: It would be better if you call `answer.length()` after accepting the string from user rather than doing it globally.

Your working code should look something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

string answer;
int maxlen;

void reverse() {
    for (int i = 0; i < maxlen; i++) {
        if (islower(answer[i])) {
            answer[i] = toupper(answer[i]);
        }
        else if (isupper(answer[i])) {
            answer[i] = tolower(answer[i]);
        }
        else if (isspace(answer[i])) {
            answer[i]=' '; 
        }
    }
    cout << "Reversed string: " + answer << endl;
}

void lower() {
    for (int i = 0; i < maxlen; i++) {
        if (isupper(answer[i])) {
            answer[i] = tolower(answer[i]);
        }
        else {
            answer[i] = answer[i];
        }
    }
    cout << "Lower case string: " + answer << endl;
}

void upper() {
    for (int i = 0; i < maxlen; i++) {
        if (islower(answer[i])) {
            answer[i] = toupper(answer[i]);
        }
        else {
            answer[i] = answer[i];
        }
    }
    cout << "Upper case string: " + answer << endl;
}

int main() {

    cout << "Please enter a word, or a series of words: " << endl;
    getline(cin,answer);
    cout << "Original string: " + answer << endl;
    maxlen = answer.length();
    reverse();
    lower();
    upper();
    return 0;
}
```

With the output:

> ```
> Please enter a word, or a series of words:
> ReVeRsAl UPPER aNd lower
> Original string: ReVeRsAl UPPER aNd lower
> Reversed string: rEvErSaL upper AnD LOWER
> Lower case string: reversal upper and lower
> Upper case string: REVERSAL UPPER AND LOWER
> ```

Answer (score 0):

```
cin >> answer[max];
```

will read exactly one character because `answer[max]` is exactly one character, the character in the array at position `max`.

`max` is 0 because you have to do things in order. For example,

```
int max = strlen(answer);
```

will provide the length of `answer` at that time this line is reached. Since the string was initialized one line earlier

```
char answer[255] = "";
```

and contains an empty string, `max` will be 0. This means `answer[max]` is `answer[0]` Nothing in the code ever changes `max`, so it will remain 0.

OK, say we  change things a little and rather than reading into a single character, we read into `answer` as a string. You will need to

```
cin.getline(answer, sizeof(answer));
```

because

```
cin >> answer;
```

will read one whitespace-delimited token. One word. Your stated goal is to read more than one word. [`istream::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline) will read everything it finds into the first parameter up to the end of the line or it finds the number of characters specified in the second parameter minus 1 (in order to reserve space for the string's null terminator). `sizeof(answer)` is literally the size of the `answer` array in bytes. We're operating in byte-sized characters so the count of characters and number of bytes are the same. Extra care must be taken if multibyte characters are being used.

This seems like a good place to recommend using [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) and [`std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) instead. They make a large number of problems, such as the maximum number of characters that can be read, vanish for the vast majority of cases.

I'm not going to use them here, though because the assignment likely has a "No `string`s" policy.

So now that we have `cin.getline(answer, sizeof(answer));` reading the user's input we can work on getting the size for `max`. We could `strlen`, but we could also use [`istream::gcount`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/gcount) to get the number of characters read by `getline`.

`main` now looks something like

```
int main() {

    cout << "Please enter a word, or a series of words: " << endl;
    cin.getline(answer, sizeof(answer));
    max = cin.gcount();

    reverse();
    lower();
    upper();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Whole bunch of stuff can go wrong at this point.

`using namespace std;` can wreak havoc on the `max` because of possible collisions with `std::max`. In general, avoid `using namespace std;` The few letters it saves you from typing often are recovered by the time wasted debugging the weird errors it can introduce.

`isupper(answer[i]);` doesn't do anything useful as others have noted in the comments. You want

```
answer[i] = toupper(static_cast<unsigned char>(answer[i]));
```

See [Do I need to cast to unsigned char before calling toupper(), tolower(), et al.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21805674/do-i-need-to-cast-to-unsigned-char-before-calling-toupper-tolower-et-al) for why that insane-and-pointless-looking cast may be necessary. Thank you HolyBlackCat for bringing that to my attention.

Self assignments like

```
answer[i] = answer[i];
```

are pointless for reasons that should be obvious once you stop and think about it.

Likewise

```
else if (isspace(answer[i])) {
    isspace(answer[i]);
 }
```

May not be particularly useful. If `answer[i]` is a space, set it to a space? It's already a space. What it would do is replace other forms of whitespace, tabs and carriage returns, with a space. Newline has already been picked off by `getline`. Also probably needs a cast similar to the one used in the `toupper` example above. I'm still reading up on that.

As hinted at above,

```
cout << answer[max];
```

is not effective. It prints out one character, and if `max` has been fixed, `answer[max]` will be the terminating null. Instead print out the whole array.

```
cout << answer;
```

General suggestions:

Don't write much code at a time. Write a few lines, a function at the most, before compiling and testing. If you had tested

```
int main() {

    cout << "Please enter a word, or a series of words: " << endl;
    cin >> answer[max];
    cout << answer;
}
```

You would have immediately seen data was not being read correctly. and fixed it before proceeding. By allowing errors to build up, you make it harder to find any one bug. You may correctly fix a bug only to find the fix undone or concealed by another bug.

Avoid using global variables. Try to place variables in the smallest possible scope. In this case, move `answer` and `max` into `main` and pass them to the other functions as parameters. This makes it a lot easier to keep track of who set what variable and when. It also helps prevent accidental [Variable Shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing).

Comment: You need a cast in `answer[i] = toupper(answer[i]);` like so: `answer[i] = toupper((unsigned char)answer[i]);`, otherwise you get UB on negative `char`s. Same for `isupper` and other similar functions.

Comment: Come to think of it, would that not also apply to `isupper`? I think I need to do a bit of reading.